# Assistance with RegexIterator and File Filtering

Tags: php, arrays, regex, object

I have the following so far:

```
function find_missing_webp_images() {

    $wp_site_root = get_home_path();
    $folder = $wp_site_root . 'wp-content/uploads';
    $jpg_pattern = '/\.jpg$/';
    $jpeg_pattern = '/\.jpeg$/';
    $png_pattern = '/\.png$/';
    $gif_pattern = '/\.gif$/';
    $webp_pattern = '/\.webp$/';

    $dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $folder );
    $ite = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $dir );
    $jpg_files = new RegexIterator( $ite, $jpg_pattern, RegexIterator::MATCH );
    $jpeg_files = new RegexIterator( $ite, $jpeg_pattern, RegexIterator::MATCH );
    $png_files = new RegexIterator( $ite, $png_pattern, RegexIterator::MATCH );
    $gif_files = new RegexIterator( $ite, $gif_pattern, RegexIterator::MATCH );
    $webp_files = new RegexIterator( $ite, $webp_pattern, RegexIterator::MATCH );
}
```

And I have a couple of questions:

1. I'm not understanding completely how to access the values saved in `$jpg_files` from the result of the `RegexIterator`. If I `var_dump($jpg_files);` I get:

`object(RegexIterator)#1490 (1) { ["replacement"]=> NULL }`

If I `var_dump($jpg_files->RegexIterator);` I get `NULL` too.

Using `foreach($jpg_files as $jpg_file)` will iterate through all the values, but `array_filter` won't work. I was trying to do the following:

```
$jpg_files_scaled = array_filter( $jpg_files, function( $val ) {
    foreach ( $jpg_files as $jpg_file ) {
        if ( $val === preg_replace( '/\.jpg$/', '', $jpg_file ) . '-scaled.jpg' ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

But after that `var_dump($jpg_files_scaled);` returns `NULL`. Even if I just straight up return true it's still `NULL`.

I can do the following to convert to an array:

```
$jpg_files_scaled = [];
foreach ($jpg_files as $jpg_file) {
    array_push( $jpg_files_scaled, $jpg_file );
}
```

But there seems like there should be a better way.

2. My goal with this is to do the following:

• Get a list of all image files in the `/wp-content/uploads/` directory

• Filter out any image if the -scaled version also exists. For example if the following 2 images both exist in the same directory:

`image.jpg`
`image-scaled.jpg`

Then the `image.jpg` should be filtered out of the list. (the same is true for the png/jpeg/gif images too).

• After that is done, the goal is to be able to check if any jpg/jpeg/png/gif version of an image exists, but the webp version is missing.

The WebP files follow the naming convention of `image.jpg.webp` or `image.png.webp`. So for example, if `image.jpg` exists, but `image.jpg.webp` does not, then `image.jpg` should be a part of the final list.

Basically looking for a way to search through very large lists of images for any missing WebP versions of images. Any help on any of the above would be very much appreciated.

************** EDIT/UPDATE ************

Thank you both! I used some of both of your answers, and here's what I have (seems to be working so far, but I need to test further and let me know if you see any potential issues with what I have):

```
function find_missing_webp_images() {

    $wp_site_root = get_home_path();
    $folder = $wp_site_root . "wp-content/uploads";
    $img_pattern = "/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/";
    $webp_pattern = "/\.webp$/";

    $dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $folder );
    $ite = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $dir );
    $img_files_obj = new RegexIterator( $ite, $img_pattern, RegexIterator::MATCH );
    $webp_files_obj = new RegexIterator( $ite, $webp_pattern, RegexIterator::MATCH );

    $img_files = [];
    $webp_files = [];

    // Convert RegexIterator objects to associative arrays with pathname as key and extensions as value
    foreach ( iterator_to_array( $img_files_obj ) as $img_file ) {
        $img_files[ $img_file->getPathname() ] = $img_file->getExtension();
    }
    foreach ( iterator_to_array( $webp_files_obj ) as $webp_file ) {
        $webp_files[ $webp_file->getPathname() ] = $webp_file->getExtension();
    }

    foreach ( $img_files as $img_file => $ext ) {

        $ext_length = strlen( $ext ) + 1;
        
        // Remove images that have a WebP version
        if ( isset( $webp_files[ $img_file . ".webp" ] ) ) {
            unset( $img_files[ $img_file ] );
            continue;
        }

        // Remove images that have a -scaled version (WebP images not created for these)
        if ( isset( $img_files[ substr( $img_file , 0, -$ext_length ) . '-scaled.' .  $ext ] ) ) {
            unset( $img_files[ $img_file ] );
        }
    }

    // Sort images so results are easier to read
    ksort( $img_files );

    foreach ( $img_files as $file => $type ) {
        echo "<pre>", $file, "</pre>";
    }
}

find_missing_webp_images();
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$jpg_files` is a `RegexIterator`, I suspect `array_filter()` is not the right option since it expects the first parameter to be an array instead of an object. The definition is type strict as below:

> array_filter ( array $array , callable|null $callback = null , int $mode = 0 ) : array

`foreach` works ok because it internally calls `current()`,`key()`,`next()`,`valid()` methods to run as a loop. So, my suggestion is to use foreach itself to filter out images who do not have a `-scaled` file for them.

```
<?php

$scaled = [];
$unscaled = [];

foreach($jpg_files as $jpg_file){
    if(preg_match('/(.+)\-scaled\.jpg/', $jpg_file, $matches) === 1){
        $scaled[ $matches[1] ] = true;
        unset($unscaled[ $matches[1].'.jpg' ]);
    }else{
        $image_name = substr($jpg_file, 0, -4); // stripping off the extension
        if(!isset( $scaled[ $image_name ] )){
            $unscaled[ $jpg_file ] = true;
        }
    }
}

$unscaled = array_keys( $unscaled );
print_r($unscaled);
```

In the above approach, we use 2 associative arrays to keep track of scaled and unscaled images. If a particular image is scaled, unset its unscaled version from `unscaled`. If an image is unscaled, add it in `unscaled` unless we find its cousin
`scaled` version to unset it in future in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Realizing I could save the pathnames as the array keys was very useful!

Comment: @Joe Could you accept by tick marking the most appropriate answer that helped you? This also helps future readers realize that there is a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, you can make use of [iterator_to_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php):

```
$jpg_files_scaled = array_filter(iterator_to_array($jpg_files), function( $val ) {
    // ...
});
```

The variable `$val` is of type [SplFileInfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) and you can get the filename using the method [getFilename](https://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getfilename.php).

---

For the second question, to get a list of all image files in the */wp-content/uploads/* directory you might use a single pattern to get all the files with  extensions in a single run using `\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)$`

Then create a list of only files that end with `-scaled` using `\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)-scaled$` and create a list for files that end with `\.webp$`

With those 3 collections, you could loop the collection for the regular filenames, and based on the presence of a `-scaled` and `.webp` version in the other 2 collections, create a final list of accepted filenames.

Comment: Thanks! iterator_to_array was a huge help! I was keeping the jpg/png/gif lists separate before because I thought I was going to have to loop through all the images each time checking for existence of the -scaled version, so I figured it would at least help make it a bit more efficient if each time it only needed to search through, for example, all the png images for a -scaled match rather than through all the images. I didn't think I could save the whole pathname as an array key (with all the slashes, periods, and such, but it seems you can. Thanks to @nice_dev for helping me realize that.